# Mongoid scaffolding tests fail on fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, automated-tests, scaffolding

When I create a new rails app with mongoid:

```
rails new tddapp --skip-active-record
cd tddapp
echo "gem 'mongoid'" >> Gemfile
bundle
rails g mongoid:config
```

And then generate a simple scaffold:

```
rails g scaffold building height:Integer name:String
```

The scaffolding is created and the minimal app runs just fine.  But the scaffold-generated tests fail with:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `buildings' for #<BuildingsControllerTest:0x007fa6afbf78d8>
```

The offending line shows that the test controller can't find the fixtures:

```
@building = buildings(:one)
```

The mongoid generator was nice enough to create fixtures in `test/fixtures/buildings.yml` indicating some level of cooperation with the whole idea of functional tests for the scaffold.

Is there some configuration setting or something I need to change to get the functional tests to load mongoid's fixtures?  Or are the scaffolding functional tests expected to fail with mongoid?  (And if so, why does mongoid bother creating fixture files?)

Comment: Are you using test-unit or rspec?

Comment: Scaffold tests subclass `ActiveSupport::TestCase` which I believe is based on test-unit / minitest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not for personal promotion, but because I got stuck on this problem several times and because I think it may helps many other people out there, I created `mongoid-fixture_set`, which is available on [github](https://github.com/Aethelflaed/mongoid-fixture_set).

It works more or less the same as `ActiveRecord::FixtureSet`, as I ported a lot of the code, you just have to tie it yourself to the test class:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include Mongoid::FixtureSet::TestHelper
  self.fixture_path = "#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures"
end
```

The same thing is done for `ActiveRecord` by rails in the gem `railties` in 'lib/rails/test_help.rb'

Comment: @izaban never tested, but if you're interested, create an issue on github. Also, I should review the code and improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoid doesn't have support for fixtures out of the box ([source](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongoid/tqlx3j88Lqw)). I recommend you forgo fixtures and go the routes of factories. [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) is an excellent option.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think it's that [fixtures is a part of ActiveRecord](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/857301), which you don't have ("`rails new tddapp --skip-active-record`").

[FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) is a pretty easy transition though. It's a bummer it's not enabled out-of-the-box though.